# Keypress event in entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I created a calculator using python tkinter , but I want to prevent typing any letters in the entry box that displays the numbers being calculated , I want the input to be only by button press to ensure that input will be numbers and mathematical operators only , this is the code that generates the box

```
textbox = Entry(MBC,font=("Helvetica",20,"bold"),text=text_Input,bd=30,
                insertwidth=4,bg="powder blue",justify="right").grid(columnspan=4)
```

if It's a text entry box , how can I make it only display the mathematical operations without accepting keyboard input ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Maybe you should try reading the guidelines to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Help us help you :)

Comment: If you only want the input to be button presses, why have a text entry widget? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not a text entry widget , it's the box that displays the numbers inputted , and when I click the mouse there and type letters they get typed but they don't affect the operations , I want to prevent them from being typed

Comment: @MazenM.Khattab Please show the code that generates the tkinter object you're talking about.

Comment: If you can type there, it sure sounds like a text entry widget. Why not give a [mcve] so we don't need to guess about code that we can't see.

Comment: That is definitely a text entry widget. As the answer below points out, the natural solution is to use a `Label` rather than an `Entry`

Comment: If you don't want the user to type, why don't you use a `Label` instead of an `Entry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can just add a state parameter in your Entry :

```py
myEntry = Entry(myWindow, state=DISABLED)
```

Here is some documentation about Entry widget : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_entry.htm

### EDIT

As someone in comments said, there is no need to use an Entry widget if you don't want the user to interact directly with. A simple Label would do the job, since you juste need to show the calculations.

Comment: Good answer (especially the part about the Label). As the documentation that you point to explicitly says "If you want to display one or more lines of text that cannot be modified by the user, then you should use the Label widget."